# What are the consequences of executing code on the next line after hooks setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I apologize in advance for asking a question that's been discussed very frequently. My question isn't about how to correctly write the code, but rather what the consequences are for doing it in a way that is not recommended. I'm uncertain if it's acceptable to execute code immediately after setting state in functional components. React seems to perform the code just fine without complaining, however every post I've seen suggests to write subsequent code in useEffect.

Please have a look at this snippet: `LoginPage.jsx`

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const user = await login({ username, password });
  setUser(user);

  // Why is this not recommended?
  history.push('/profile');
}
```

`user` state belongs to the top-level component `App`, and it must be defined for `ProfilePage` to render without crashing. `user` is initially `undefined`.

In this particular scenario, `user` state will be updated and then the browser will redirect to /profile without any visible issues. This seems to happen synchronously, as `ProfilePage` renders without crashing.

**context**

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/login'>
        <LoginPage setUser={setUser} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/profile'>
        <ProfilePage user={user} />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

```
function ProfilePage({ user }) {
  return <div>{user.username}</div>
}
```

```
function LoginPage({ setUser }) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const history = useHistory();

  function handleChangeUsername(e) {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleChangePassword(e) {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  }

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = await login({ username, password });
    setUser(user);
    history.push('/profile');
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" value={username} onChange={handleChangeUsername} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="password" value={password} onChange={handleChangePassword} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not recommended because the `useState` hook updates state asynchronously and you can't ***depend*** on state being updated before you navigate away from the component. If you don't have much else going on in the component and the browser doesn't have to wait for I/O, then you may never actually see a problem. However, it might trip you up later on and it will take you forever to figure it out because it had never been a problem until that moment.

Best to follow best practices with a `useEffect` hook.